# Two functions on same MouseClickEvent C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseclick-event

I'm having some difficulty making two separate functions inside the same MouseClick Eventhandler on a checkbox in C# using Winforms.

If the user clicks the checkbox it's supposed to come a warning for the user to verify the action. If the user un-checks the checkbox a different warning will show for the user to verify the action.

My code is the following:

```
private bool alreadyClicked = false;

private void myCheckbox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!myCheckbox.Checked && !alreadyClicked)
        {
            DialogResult d1 = MessageBox.Show("Some text1", "Some title1", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (d1 == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                myCheckbox.Checked = true;
                alreadyClicked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                myCheckbox.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        if (myCheckbox.Checked && alreadyClicked)
        {
            DialogResult d2 = MessageBox.Show("Some text2", "Some title2", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (d2 == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                myCheckbox.Checked = false;
                alreadyClicked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                myCheckbox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the second if-statement checking if the checkbox is checked and if the "alreadyClicked"-variable is true triggers when the user verifies the first action (to check the checkbox), which happens due to the "alreadyClicked"-variable being true before the event closes. I'm stuck and would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `else if` instead of second `if`?

Comment: @donggas90 I didn't but I wish I did so I wouldn't have to post this stupid question haha. Thank you, that did the trick.

Comment: Is there a reason for using MouseClick instead of CheckedChanged?

Comment: @Fildor Yeah i've set the checkbox "Autocheck" property on false. The form is going to be viewed by both regular users and admins but only admins are allowed to change the box. When I have the same code on the "CheckedChanged" event nothing happens (I think because of the AutoCheck property being false).

Answer (score 1):

Well let's look at the two if statements.

When the checkbox is first clicked and the first messagebox will be answered with yes, you set the checkbox and the `alreadyClicked` variable to `true`. Right afterwards in the second if statement you check if those two values are true. Which they are of course because we just set them to true. Therefore the second if statement will be true and the second message will be displayed.

To prevent this behaviour you could use an `else if (myCheckbox.Checked && alreadyClicked)` after the first if statement. In that case the second if statement will only be processed, when the first one results to `false`.

You could also consider if the bool variable `alreadyClicked` is really adding any value here. As of my understanding it always has the same value as the checkbox itself.